# I have a list of dictionary. I want to sort based on value and create another list of dictionary for common values

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I have a list of dictionary. I want to sort based on value and create another list of dictionary for common values.

[image]

```py
 listofDictRecords = [{'storageID': 1, 'storageDate': 2022-12-22, 'volume':1.5}, 
    {'storageID': 1, 'storageDate': '2022-12-24', 'volume':3.5}
    {'storageID': 2, 'storageDate': '2022-12-25', 'volume':4.5},
    {'storageID': 2, 'storageDate': '2022-12-26', 'volume':5.5},
    {'storageID': 1, 'storageDate': '2022-12-23', 'volume':2.5}]
```

I want to convert it into the format below:

```py
requireOutput = {[{'storageID' : 1, 'storageDateVolume' : [{'storageDate' : '2022-12-22','volume':1.5},
                    {'storageDate' : 2022-12-23, 'volume':2.5},{'storageDate' : '2022-12-24', 'volume':3.5}]},
                    {'storageID' : 2, 'storageDateVolume' : [{'storageDate' : '2022-12-25', 'volume':4.5},
                    {'storageDate' : '2022-12-26', 'volume':5.5}]}
```

Comment: Your output format is invalid.

Comment: Hi @KlausD. can you help me anything near to that require output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use groupby (from itertools) after sorting the list of dictionaries on their storageID:

```
listofDictRecords = [{'storageID': 1, 'storageDate': '2022-12-22', 'volume':1.5}, 
    {'storageID': 1, 'storageDate': '2022-12-24', 'volume':3.5},
    {'storageID': 2, 'storageDate': '2022-12-25', 'volume':4.5},
    {'storageID': 2, 'storageDate': '2022-12-26', 'volume':5.5},
    {'storageID': 1, 'storageDate': '2022-12-23', 'volume':2.5}]

from itertools import groupby

sortedDictRecords = sorted(listofDictRecords,key=lambda d:d['storageID'])
groups = groupby(sortedDictRecords,key=lambda d:d['storageID'])
requiredOutput = [ {'storageID':sid,
                    'storageVolume':[(r.pop('storageID'),r)[1] for r in record]}
                   for sid,record in groups ]
```

output:

```
print(requiredOutput)
[{'storageID': 1, 'storageVolume': [{'storageDate': '2022-12-22', 'volume': 1.5}, {'storageDate': '2022-12-24', 'volume': 3.5}, {'storageDate': '2022-12-23', 'volume': 2.5}]}, 
 {'storageID': 2, 'storageVolume': [{'storageDate': '2022-12-25', 'volume': 4.5}, {'storageDate': '2022-12-26', 'volume': 5.5}]}]
```